# changing email resource.pending_reconfirmation? no longer works with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, confirmation

After upgrading to rails 4, 
I have problem with

```
resource.pending_reconfirmation?
```

In registrations#edit view i have:

```
  - if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
    %div
      Currently waiting confirmation for: #{resource.unconfirmed_email}.
      %br
      Please click the link in the email to confirm
  .ruler
```

it seems devise_mapping.confirmable? == true but right after an email change resource.pending_reconfirmation? keeps false.

Why is this happening and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If found that there is a problem with the resource.pending_reconfirmation? and the fields that is trying to use. I soleved this using:

```
  - if devise_mapping.confirmable? && (not resource.confirmed?)
    %div
      Currently waiting confirmation for: #{resource.email}.
      %br
      Please click the link in the email to confirm
  .ruler
```